# Android client sends only one message to java server

Tags: android, sockets

I am developing a simple chat application. Android client and a java desktop server. I am facing a problem that my client sends only a single message to server. Server code is working on java client so only android code have some problem. 
Android Client

```
private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";
private Socket socket;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                   String str = et.getText().toString();


                 out.println(str);   
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       }
     });    
}



class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your thread finishes its job and it's no longer available for you.

Comment: You may want to have a look over Services and ThreadPools, your chat app needs to always have a background running resource to send/receive messages.